# How to set IP_TTL for a packet in python?

Tags: python, ssl, scapy

In the below code. I am sending GET request to a HTTPS website and printing response. Is it possible to set IP_TTL for the GET request packet ? How caan I do that ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    # This import works from the project directory
    from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import *
except ImportError:
    # If you installed this package via pip, you just need to execute this
    from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *

tls_version = TLSVersion.TLS_1_2
ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
extensions = [TLSExtension() / TLSExtECPointsFormat(),
              TLSExtension() / TLSExtSupportedGroups()]


def tls_client(ip):
    with TLSSocket(client=True) as tls_socket:
        try:
            tls_socket.connect(ip)
            print("Connected to server: %s" % (ip,))
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Failed to open connection to server: %s" % (ip,), file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            try:
                server_hello, server_kex = tls_socket.do_handshake(tls_version, ciphers, extensions)
                server_hello.show()
            except TLSProtocolError as tpe:
                print("Got TLS error: %s" % tpe, file=sys.stderr)
                tpe.response.show()
            else:
                resp = tls_socket.do_round_trip(TLSPlaintext(data="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: localhost\r\n\r\n"))
                print("Got response from server")
                resp.show()
            finally:
                print(tls_socket.tls_ctx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        server = (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    else:
        server = ("google.com", 443)
    tls_client(server)
```

The above code is taken this link.  [https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/examplesfull_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/examples/full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py)

Comment: have you searched for anything elsewhere? I'm getting a lot of hits when just googling for "python IP_TTL".

Comment: @IrmendeJong All those options are not working for me.       Even after adding `tls_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 1)` before sending GET request. I am getting response from the webserver

Comment: maybe the TLSSocket wrapper doesn't support IP_TTL....?

Comment: Why not go to the source and testing of Python, written in Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Tools/demo/mcast.py I tried to make it work on direct UDP without success.